# removing a parent in a knockout function from nested loop

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

In my view I am looping through an observableArray (itemGroup) that has one property that is also an observableArray (item). I have a method to remove an entire itemGroup and one to remove an item from and itemGroup but I would like to add in some logic along the lines of it there is only 1 item left in the group removing that item should also remove the itemGroup.

here is an example of the relevant parts of my view model and view.

my JS

```
var ItemModel = function(item) {
   var self = this;
   self.name = ko.observable(item.name);
   self.price = ko.observable(item.price);
};

var ItemGroupModel = function(itemGroup) {
   var self = this;
   self.order = ko.observable(itemGroup.order);
   self.items = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(itemGroup.items, function(item){
      return new ItemModel(item);
   }));
   self.type = ko.observable(item.type);

   self.removeItem = function(item) {
      self.items.remove(item);
   }
};

var ViewModel = function(data) {
   var self = this;
   self.itemGroups = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(data.itemGroups, function(itemGroup) {
     return new ItemGroupModel(item);
   }));

  // some other properties and methods
   self.removeItemGroup = function(itemGroup) {
     self.itemGroups.remove(itemGroup);
  }
};
```

My View

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: {data: VM.itemGroups, as: 'itemGroup'}">
   <li>
       <button data-bind="click: $root.VM.removeItemGroup">X</button>
       <ul data-bind="foreach: {data: itemGroup.items, as: 'item'}">
          <li>
             <!-- ko if: itemGroup.items().length > 1 -->
             <button data-bind="click: itemGroup.removeItem">X</button>
             <!-- /ko -->
             <!-- ko ifnot: itemGroup.items().length > 1 -->
             <button data-bind="click: function () { $root.VM.removeItemGroup($parent) }">X</button>
             <!-- /ko -->
           </li>
       </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

This works but to me it isnt ideal. It is my understanding that knockout should help me get away from using an anonymous function like "function () { $root.VM.removeItemGroup($parent) }" but I am not sure how to do it another way. Also removing the if and ifnot statements would be good to clean up as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I would like to give my solution**

send index of itemGroups and items as argument to remove method.

**Hope you know how to send index**

Then check the length of itemGroups

```
self.remove(itemGroupsIndex,itemsIndex) {
 var itemGroupsLength = self.itemGroups()[itemGroupsIndex].items().length;
  if(itemGroupsLength = 1) {

   self.itemGroups.remove(itemGroupsIndex);

  }
  else {

   self.itemGroups()[itemGroupsIndex].items.remove(itemsIndex);

  }
 };
```

Comment: how do I reference this in my view? is it possible to do without using an anonymous function?

Comment: not possible. you should use any of these anonymous function or visible binding or what you have done